# OOP: want to define a function passing three arguments - to find cell, locate its column and populate blank cells

Tags: excel, vba, oop

I have written this code for an OOP in VBA, so I can reuse the same function, while only changing the arguments and calling it in later macros. The point of this code is to create a function with three arguments: to locate the sheet, locate a specific column heading and then what to fill the blanks with. I have limited previous experience with python and java, but cannot manage to get this VBA setup. I think I am very close, but the code needs more tweaks and maybe there are more elegant solutions. The last four lines are for me to see what the variables are as checks.

```
Sub FillBlanks(sheetname As String, findcolumnn As String, filler As String)
    Dim blankcells As Range, columnforchange As Range, abc As Integer
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("A1:ZZ10000")
    Set foundcell = .Find(What:=findcolumn, LookIn:=xlValues,         SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True)
    abc = foundcell.Column
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname)
            Set columnforchange = .Range(CStr(abc) & ":" & CStr(abc))
                For Each blankcells In columnforchange
                    If IsEmpty(blankcells.Value) Or blankcells.Value = vbNullString Then
                        blankcells.Value = filler
                    End If
                Next blankcells
        End With
    End With
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = abc
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = filler
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value = sheetname
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value = findcolumn
```

End Sub

Comment: currently what doesnt work?

Comment: On the range it populated my row instead of the column. could i get more clarification how I should specify the range? sometimes the find function also returns the second result (ie more than one column has the same phrase - how do i lock it to a specific column). Another problem, when populating the row, it does not stop at the last column, but instead fills all blank cells. The spreadsheet I am working with has variable changing amount of rows and columns

Answer (score 0):

```
Set columnforchange = .Range(CStr(abc) & ":" & CStr(abc))
```

will set `columnforchange` to a row.  eg. `Range("10:10")`  --> Row 10

Try

```
Set columnforchange = .Columns(abc)
```

With regard to your `.Find`, try using the `After:=` argument to specify a starting point. (e.g:  `After:= .Cells(1,1)` Understand that your `After:=` will not be searched first -- it will be searched last.  And, if it is not the first one you want to find, you may need to run your .Find more than once (or use .FindNext)

There are other tweaks that could be made:

- Use the Long data type rather than Integer.  In VBA, Integer is limited to around 2^15-1, and will internally get converted to a Long anyway.
- If your empty cells are truly empty, you might be able to use the .SpecialCells property to find and fill them in one step, instead of looping.

Comment: I tried using the .Columns mode, however, for whatever reason Excel does not support this functions for me - "Object defined error" when I try and use it. Instead I made another sub to change the number into a letter. I am still having problems with executing this code. Instead of using the find function, I am trying to loop only through the first row, to locate the column, otherwise the program is quite slow and incorrectly identifies the column. Comparing strings is quite slow. What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Is there a way of me turning the first row into an array and checking through an array? Would that be quicker?

Comment: the find function messes up once you try and put a string through it like in my code. it works perfectly if you define what you would like to find i.e. Find="this_is_what_im_looking_for", but does not support Find = variable_string

Comment: @KamilKurdziel What version of Excel? There should be no problem with either of those. Either there is something incorrect about how you are implementing, or there is something peculiar about your data.  I suppose there could be an issue with the MAC version of Excel -- I cannot test that.  But I doubt it on these kinds of problems.  I suggest you upload a copy of a workbook (with sensitive info removed) demonstrating the problem to some public file sharing site (**NOT a site that requires registration or login to access**), and post the link here.